# Thread does not give output unless an explicit fflush function is invoked when using output redirection

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, io-redirection

I am writing a multi-threaded program. The structure of the program is as given below

```
int main()
{

    printf("To Call threads\n");
    thread1=pthread_create(&trd1,NULL,process1,(void *)sleepTimeForP1);
    thread2=pthread_create(&trd2,NULL,process2,(void *)sleepTimeForP2);
    pthread_join(trd1, NULL);
    pthread_join(trd2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The code for thread is

```
void *process1 (void *sleepTimeForP1)
{
    int *tsleepTimeForP1 = (int *)sleepTimeForP1;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        printf("inside thread\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }

}
```

The code works fine, and prints the output when no output redirection is done. But when output redirection is given, no ouput is obtained in the file. Now If I give explicit `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf()` statement, I am getting the desired output. Why am I required to give the explicit fflush() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C99 §7.19.3[7]:

> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and **standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device**.

'Fully buffered' (vs 'line buffered'): C99 §7.19.3[3]

> When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered.

So, when standard-output is interactive (e.g. a shell) it is line-buffered. But when you redirect it to a file it becomes fully buffered and you must use `fflush`.